# iOS MonoTouch navigation middle buttons

Tags: button, xamarin.ios, navigation

Some Apps (like Facebook's) have buttons in the middle of the navigation section (instead of text title). How could I support right/left, and add middle button region the navigation menu, in MonoTouch?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure. Can you add (a link to) a screenshot to the application ? (or to a mockup of what you want to do ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a view or a toolbar or basically what you want that is a subclass of UIView, and add the following code.
(don't forget that you uiviewcontroller should be embedded in uinavigationcontroller)

```
this.NavigationItem.TitleView = YourTitleView;
```